# Rails 3 template: strange beahaviour of inject_into_file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, templates

I am writing a template for Rails 3 (you can find it [here](https://gist.github.com/2489048)), and I'm having troubles with the following lines:

```
# 8. config/database.yml modifications
if yes?("Do you want to set the database host to '/var/run/postgresql'?")
  inject_into_file "config/database.yml", " host: /var/run/postgresql\n", :after => "development:\n"


  # FIXME these two won't work :(((( why????
  # inject_into_file "config/database.yml", " host: /var/run/postgresql\n", :after => "production:\n"
  # inject_into_file "config/database.yml", " host: /var/run/postgresql\n", :after => "test:\n"


  # Not finding other solutions, I rewrite the two blocks above with two seds
  run %q(sed -i '/test:/a\ \ host: /var/run/postgresql' config/database.yml)
  run %q(sed -i '/production:/a\ \ host: /var/run/postgresql' config/database.yml)
end
```

That is, the first inject_to_file works, and in config/database.yml I have

```
development:
  host: /var/run/postgresql
```

but the other two inject_to_file are successfully applied, but don't modify config/database.yml! So I have

```
test:
  adapter: postgresql
```

and

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
```

Comment: Have you checked it's not something "obvious" like weird characters or  extraneous carriage returns (`\r`) in your `database.yml` that is preventing the substitution from triggering (e.g. run `od -c` on the file and check that everything is where it's supposed to be).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to specify the `:force => true` option to inject the same text multiple times.
See:

http://rdoc.info/github/wycats/thor/master/Thor/Actions#insert_into_file-instance_method

This version works for me:

https://gist.github.com/2573325

Don't ask me why that option makes any sense, tho.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled here looking for a solution to a slightly different problem:

The rails docs say to use inject_into_file in this manner

```
inject_into_file 'name_of_file.rb', after: "#The code goes below this line. Don't forget the Line break at the end\n" do <<-'RUBY'
  puts "Hello World"
RUBY
end
```

However, that was not working for me all the time. In some cases, it actually would output the word "puts" and some ruby code into the file I was trying to inject.

Finally I figured out that you can just pass `inject_into_file` a string and it's a lot easier.

```
inject_into_file 'name_of_file.rb', :after => "#The code goes below this line. Don't forget the Line break at the end\n" do
  "Hello World"
end
```

Comment: I think `inject_into_file` is now changed to `append_to_file`: http://rdoc.info/gems/thor/0.18.1/Thor/Actions:append_to_file

Comment: I don't see any options for passing before and after locations in append_to_file, though?

Comment: I made a mistake: it's `insert_into_file` with an alias to `inject_into_file`: http://rdoc.info/gems/thor/0.18.1/Thor/Actions#insert_into_file-instance_method